# vuejs to trigger one of 3 potential methods based off of data

Tags: vue.js

I want to trigger one of 3 methods based on what data is found in subdescription. As of now it works fine if the data is "Video" and if anything else, it triggers the myClick2 method. I am trying to add a 3rd option in that checks to see if it says "Poster". If it says poster, to trigger another method (myClicky). Anything else, show the myClick2.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   chocs:[]
  },
  methods: {
 handleTileClick: function(){
    alert("test");
    },
    myClick2: function(){
    alert("test2");
    },
    myClicky: function(){
    alert("tested");
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<div class="card" v-on:click="choc.subdescription==='Video'?handleTileClick():myClick2()"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new method that accepts the `subdescription` and returns the function to be called. This would be used as a value for the click handler:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
   chocs: [ 
     { subdescription: 'Video' }, 
     { subdescription: 'Poster' }, 
     { subdescription: 'Other' } 
   ]
  }),
  methods: {
    getOnClickFn: function(subdescription) {
      let fn;
      switch(subdescription) {
        case 'Video':
          fn = this.handleTileClick;
          break;
        case 'Poster':
          fn = this.myClicky;
          break;
        default:
          fn = this.myClick2;
          break;
      }
      return fn;
    },
    handleTileClick: function() { alert("test"); },
    myClick2:        function() { alert("test2"); },
    myClicky:        function() { alert("tested"); }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div 
    class="card" 
    v-for="{ subdescription } in chocs"
    :key="subdescription"
    @click="() => getOnClickFn(subdescription)()"
  >Click {{subdescription}}</div>
</div>
```